# How to make two elements line up perfectly?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm still trying to finish this theme I'm working on. Atm I'm trying to implement header support, and it's not going to well with my layout. Everything was fine until I added this line:

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" />
```

So, header currently looks like this:

```
<hgroup class="blog-header">
        <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="" />
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
        <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        <?php the_breadcrumb(); ?>
    </hgroup>
```

Here's the thing, this works fine when there's no header image, however when adding one, it messes up my styling for the site description - which bumps up a few pixels from where it was. The title and the description is supposed to be inline with each other, and I'm not sure how to fix this without one of the scenarios making it wrong..

Here's my style for these:

```
.site-title {
font-family: 'Bree Serif', Georgia, serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-style: uppercase;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;
margin: 0 0 0 90px;
padding: 60px 25px 60px 0;
float: left;
}

.site-description {
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
color: #c9c9c9;
padding: 68px 25px 60px 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything when I put this into jsfiddle. Can you provide one or is your site up?

Comment: Yes, im using my domain as the building site, it's [here](http://michaelmehlum.com)

Comment: Can you update that site with the image placed in there so I can mess with it? Currently it looks like it isn't in there. I don't see this: <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="" /> in the page.

Comment: Oh, sorry, just realized I've been working locally... I'll update that site with the updated theme :) 20 sec

Comment: well I don't see it nudging 10 px, I only see a couple but from what I can tell so far the image is in it's right place. Give me a bit to see if I can figure this out.

Comment: Thanks :) That's what's weird, image in the right place, but when I remove it, the text falls to the right place...

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is going to be bizarre but if you go into your body class in your reset.css, and change line-height=1 to line-height=4px; it shifts it upwards. Or even just changing from 1 to 1px; it works.

[image]

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried both locally and on the site, but doesn't work for me.. Even tried emptying all cache, deleting ds_store files, nothing.. :(

Comment: If you have firebug, try it there, and if it works, then it must be in that css

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood, the description is supposed to match the the baseline of the site-title.. It's not supposed to be centered..

Comment: thats what I thought, and when I change the line height , thats what happens